# MySQL Select first N rows from table with rows related to another one

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a repayments table which has 16 rows for each loan that the repayments belong.

```
Repayments
loanid  repid  amnt
--------------------
a1      r1     1,100
a1      r2     1,100
|       |      |
a1      r16    1,105
b2      s1     2,500
b2      s2     2,500
|       |      |
b2      s16    2,510
|       |      |

Loans
loanid  othercolumns...
-----------------------
a1
b2
|
blahid
|
```

LoanIds are some string.
RepaymentIds too

I'm looking for a query which gives me the first 15 rows from each repayments for every loan.

```
loanid  repid  amnt
a1      r1     1,100
a1      r2     1,100
|       |      |
a1      r15    1,105
b2      s1     2,500
b2      s2     2,500
|       |      |
b2      s15    2,510
|       |      |
```

Is this possible with SQL? and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming rep isn't sequential, in which case you can use `WHERE rep <= 15`, then you need to introduce a row number per group.  MySql does not have a built in row number function like other databases, but you can use `user defined variables` to achieve the same result

```
select *
from (
  select loan, rep, amnt, @row:=if(@prevLoan=loan, @row+1, 1) rn, @prevLoan:=loan
  from repayments
    join (select @row:=0, @prevLoan:=0) t
  order by loan, rep
  ) t
where rn <= 15
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a72/4)

Comment: I should be more generic with my examples... loan id is some string, not a sequential Id number as shown, repayment id too. let me edit that...

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. -- should still work the same way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ad3e/1

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. -- you'll need to explain further.  You need to order by loan to create your grouping.  In regards to the other field, that just depends on how you want to return your results (which 15 records to keep per group).  Should still be the same logic...

Comment: oh... I was copying something wrong from your solution. It's working now! :)

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. -- no worries, glad we figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

if you have some sort of ID in the other table then a simple inner join should do the trick..something like:

```
select t1.column1, t1.column2 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1id
limit 15
```

hope u get it, if not post the columns and table names and i could try to give you the query you need, but this should get u started.

Comment: nope, limit won't work, since this will give me only the first 15 results of all the query, not the first 15 results for EVERY table2 rows...